# why is the code giving different result when I am explicitly defining the value variable in a decimal to binary recursive function?

Tags: python, recursion

Here i declared value=value//2

```
def dec2bin(value,lis=[]):
    if value>1:
        value=value//2
        dec2bin(value)
    lis.append(value%2)
    return lis
    
print(dec2bin(5))
```

returns [1,1,0]

Here I just used value//2 within the function

```
def dec2bin(value,lis=[]):
    if value>1:
        dec2bin(value//2)
    lis.append(value%2)
    return lis
    
print(dec2bin(5))
```

returns [1,0,1]

Comment: `value=value//2` changes the value of `value`.

Comment: Try `print(value, lis)` before entering recursion, to see how values evolve in time.

Comment: You are assigning ```value``` as ```value//2``` But simply doing ```value//2``` will not change the value of ```value```

Answer (score 1):

There are many things wrong here.  The most surprising is probably ["Least Astonishment" and the Mutable Default Argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132941/least-astonishment-and-the-mutable-default-argument) which means that `lis=[]` probably doesn't do what you expect here.

Secondly, you are not recording the result from your recursive call.

Try this instead:

```py
def dec2bin(value):
      lis = []
      if value > 1:
        lis = dec2bin(value//2)
      lis.append(value % 2)
      return lis
```